# Calculate Mean Absolute Error for each row of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Below is a sample of pandas dataframe that I'm working with.
I want to calculate mean absolute error for each row but only considering relevant columns for values of ID column.

There may be 2 4,6 or 8 columns relevant to values of ID column. For example, relevant columns for 'id4' is 'id4_signal1_true' and 'id4_signal1_pred'. for 'id1' its 'id1_signal1_true', 'id1_signal2_true', 'id1_signal1_pred' and 'id1_signal2_pred'.

```
import pandas as pd
list = [['id4',0.37,0.97,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.38,0.95,0.2,0.5,0.23],
        ['id1',0.41,0.44,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.41,0.48,0.2,0.5,0.23],
        ['id3',0.41,0.44,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.41,0.48,0.2,0.5,0.23]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['ID','id1_signal1_true','id1_signal2_true','id4_signal1_true','id3_signal1_true',
                                  'id3_signal2_true','id1_signal1_pred','id1_signal2_pred','id4_signal1_pred',
                                  'id3_signal1_pred','id3_signal2_pred'])
```

I want to calculate mae for each row only considering the specific relevant columns.
for example, for the first row, it should be like
`mean(abs(id4_signal1_true-id4_signal1_pred))`
for the second row, it should be
`mean(abs('id1_signal1_true'-'id1_signal1_pred'),abs('id1_signal2_true'-'id1_signal2_pred'))`

below is a screenshot of how the output looks like. MAE is the column which i want to get
[image]

I used the below code to solve this. this is working fine. But the only issue is i have around 2 million rows and this takes hours. i want to find a efficient way to do this. Highly appreciated your help on this

```
Attack = df
ID_MAE = []
for id in range(len(Attack['ID'])):

    signals = np.array(Attack[Attack.columns[Attack.columns.str.contains(Attack.ID[id])]]) # select columns relevant to current ID
    signal = signals[id]  # select only the specific row (id)

    no_of_signals = int(len(signal)/2) # identify number of signals
    reshaped_arr = np.reshape(signal, (2,no_of_signals))
    signal_true = reshaped_arr[0]  # array for true values
    signal_pred = reshaped_arr[1]  # array for predicted values

    # mae calculation
    MAE = np.mean(np.abs(signal_true - signal_pred), axis=0)
    ID_MAE.append(MAE)

df['MAE'] = ID_MAE
```

Comment: over your 1 million rows, is the ID column unique?

Comment: Did you try Numba?

Comment: Yes, ID column has 10 unique values (id0, id1, ... id9). for each ID, there are 2,4,6 or 8 columns with true or pred suffix (eg: id1_signal1_true and id1_signal1_pred)

Comment: @keramat No. Don't know about it. Can i use it with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df2 = df.set_index('ID').apply(lambda x: (np.array(list(map(lambda t: t[1], sorted(x[(ser:=pd.Series(x.index.to_list()))[ser.str.startswith(x.name)]].to_dict().items())))).reshape(-1,2)),  axis=1)
df2.apply(lambda arr: np.array([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in arr]).mean())
```

output:

```
ID
id4    0.01
id1    0.02
id3    0.08
dtype: float64
```

### UPDATE:

or you can:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: (np.array(list(map(lambda t: t[1], sorted(x[(ser:=pd.Series(x.index.to_list()))[ser.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items())))).reshape(-1,2)),  axis=1)
df["MAE"] = df2.apply(lambda arr: np.array([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in arr]).mean())
```

well, well, well... now explanation.. let's go :))
*notice: I explain update part*

what is problem? you are some columns and rows... and for each row, you want to have corresponding columns... mean only columns that `startswith` column's `name`...Hmm, new idea...

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.index.str.startswith(x.ID), axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    [False, False, False, True, False, False, Fals...
1    [False, True, True, False, False, False, True,...
2    [False, False, False, False, True, True, False...
```

As you see, for every row, give that that each column start with (is correspond) or not (notice: `ID` is `id4`,`id1`,...)

ok, next you must get all columns that are correspond, using:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (ser:=pd.Series(x.index.to_list()))[ser.str.startswith(x.ID)], axis=1)
```

output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   NaN NaN id4_signal1_true    NaN NaN NaN NaN id4_signal1_pred    NaN NaN
1   id1_signal1_true    id1_signal2_true    NaN NaN NaN id1_signal1_pred    id1_signal2_pred    NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN id3_signal1_true    id3_signal2_true    NaN NaN NaN id3_signal1_pred    id3_signal2_pred
```

as you know, you can pass a list of boolean as index to pandas series and get all columns that are `True`...

wait a minute, it can be more simple... (because `x.index` is series, itself)

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]], axis=1)
```

ok,we get all correspond columns, so what? nothing, as you see, some columns are `NaN` and we must rid of them, so convert data to `list` of `name-value` pair using `to_dict().items()`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items(), axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    ((id4_signal1_true, 0.21), (id4_signal1_pred, ...
1    ((id1_signal1_true, 0.41), (id1_signal2_true, ...
2    ((id3_signal1_true, 0.54), (id3_signal2_true, ...
dtype: object
```

why we need `name`s? because we need to calculate `MAE` between correct pairs...

ok, now we have pairs, but in incorrect order... how can we sort it? we now that correct pairs have same name, except in last part: `pred` and `true`... so let's sort them based on names:

```
df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x[(ser:=pd.Series(x.index.to_list()))[ser.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items()),  axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    [(id4_signal1_pred, 0.2), (id4_signal1_true, 0...
1    [(id1_signal1_pred, 0.41), (id1_signal1_true, ...
2    [(id3_signal1_pred, 0.5), (id3_signal1_true, 0...
```

oh, yes, they are in in correct order and we can calculate `MAE` for each pair and so, we can rid of names, so `map` on each `list` and get `second element`s:

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(map(lambda t: t[1], sorted(x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items()))),  axis=1)
```

output:

```
0                 [0.2, 0.21]
1    [0.41, 0.41, 0.48, 0.44]
2     [0.5, 0.54, 0.23, 0.11]
dtype: object
```

ok... now, we can calculate `MAE` for each pair, but how we can convert each `list` to `list` of `pair`s... hmmm... NumPy!!! and using `.reshape(-1,2)`
we convert it to pairs and calculate `MAE` for each pair:

```
(np.array(list(map(lambda t: t[1], sorted(x[(ser:=pd.Series(x.index.to_list()))[ser.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items())))).reshape(-1,2))
```

output:

```
0                   [[0.2, 0.21]]
1    [[0.41, 0.41], [0.48, 0.44]]
2     [[0.5, 0.54], [0.23, 0.11]]
dtype: object
```

wait a minute... we use NumPy... and why don't use further?

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.array(sorted(x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items()))[:,1].astype(float).reshape(-1,2),  axis=1)
```

convert `sorted` output to `numpy.array` and get second element using: `[:,1]`
now, just calculate `MAE` for each `pair`:

```
df2.apply(lambda arr: np.array([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in arr]))
```

output:

```
0                         [0.009999999999999981]
1                     [0.0, 0.03999999999999998]
2    [0.040000000000000036, 0.12000000000000001]
dtype: object
```

we calculate absolute difference for each pair... and, again, we can make it simpler:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(np.diff(np.array(sorted(x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items()))[:,1].astype(float).reshape(-1,2))), axis=1)
```

and, finally, we calculate `mean` for each `numpy.array`

### The third and more simple and fast manner:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(np.diff(np.array(sorted(x[x.index[x.index.str.startswith(x.ID)]].to_dict().items()))[:,1].astype(float).reshape(-1,2))).mean(), axis=1)
```

I attempted to explain it in simple word, hope be helpfull

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the same code. but I get this error
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @SampathRajapaksha because you define your variable by name: `list` please reset your kernel and rename it to `lst` and **dont name any variable with builtin names** :) `list = [['id4',0.37,0.97,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.38,0.95,0.2,0.5,0.23],
        ['id1',0.41,0.44,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.41,0.48,0.2,0.5,0.23],
        ['id3',0.41,0.44,0.21,0.54,0.11,0.41,0.48,0.2,0.5,0.23]]`

Comment: Thank you. Now it's working. but the output is something else for df2. am i missing something?
`ID
id4                   [[0.2, 0.21]]
id1    [[0.41, 0.41], [0.48, 0.44]]
id3     [[0.5, 0.54], [0.23, 0.11]]`

Comment: @SampathRajapaksha No, but why `df2`? it is just a temp variable. assign last line to a variable, like: `df['MAE'] = df2.apply(lambda arr: np.array([abs(a[0] - a[1]) for a in arr]).mean())`

Comment: @SampathRajapaksha but before that add this line: `df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)` or see **UPDATE**

Comment: This is working fine now. Highly appreciate it if you could explain the used method

Comment: @SampathRajapaksha I edit my post :)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the best explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1. Split the columns into a three-level header
2. `groupby` ID and Signal and get the MAE
3. Select the correct MAE for each row
4. Collapse the multi-level header back to a single level.

```
df = df.set_index("ID").rename_axis(None)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_",expand=True)
df = df.rename_axis(["ID","Signal","Type"],axis=1).sort_values(["ID","Signal"],axis=1)
MAE = df.groupby(["ID","Signal"], axis=1).diff().abs().groupby("ID", axis=1).mean()
df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)

df["MAE"] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: MAE.at[x,x])

>>> df
     id1_signal1_true  id1_signal1_pred  ...  id4_signal1_pred   MAE
id4              0.37              0.38  ...               0.2  0.01
id1              0.41              0.41  ...               0.2  0.02
id3              0.41              0.41  ...               0.2  0.08

[3 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working fine with a sample of a dataset. but when i try to apply this to 2 million rows it crashes the computer. Is this create a very large dataframe?